# Change the photo size Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app, the user could take pictures and store in my sqlce database. The problem is the size of the pictures that needs to be send by internet and the length of the size is at least 4mb by picture!

I need to reduce the size of the pictures after they are captured in my app.

Here is my code:

```
private void camera_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.Error == null)
        {
            image = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

            image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            Imagem.Source = image;
        }
    }
```

To get the image to save the image to my sqlce database, I'm using this code:

```
    byte[] ConvertImage()
    {
        if (image == null) return null;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
        wb.SaveJpeg(ms, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Even save to Jpeg format, the size in bytes are still too big in my opinion.

Comment: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ or http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/imaging let us know if you need specific code

Comment: @FunksMaName I'm already using writeablebitmapex but I don't figured out how to decrease the picture sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to adjust the size of the image. Resize the image resolution to the smaller one:

[WritableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) sample code:

```
// Resizes the WriteableBitmap to 200px wide and 300px high using a bilinear interpolation method
var resized = writeableBmp.Resize(200, 300, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear)
```

and/or adjust(decrease) the quality (affect image size):

```
public static void SaveJpeg(
    this WriteableBitmap bitmap,
    Stream targetStream,
    int targetWidth,
    int targetHeight,
    int orientation,
    int quality
)
```

You can use both methods.

Answer (score 0):

try this to your code

```
byte[] ConvertImage()
{
    if (image == null) return null;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
    wb.SaveJpeg(ms, image.PixelWidth/4, image.PixelHeight/4, 0, 100);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

you can also do /2 or whatever you required